How to get and set values which they have effect on each other in Swift?
I want to create a struct with two values, a and b, where a must always be equal to b + 5, and b must always be equal to a - 5. I've tried different approaches to implement this, but I'm unsure which is the most efficient and maintainable. Could you help me optimize it and find the best solution?
struct MyType1 {
    
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = a - 5
    }
    
    init(b: Int) {
        self.b = b
        self.a = b - 5
    }
    
    var a: Int {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            print("didSet for a")
            if (oldValue != a) && (b != (a - 5)) {
                b = a - 5
            }
        }
    }
    
    var b: Int {
        didSet(oldValue) {
            print("didSet for b")
            if (oldValue != b) && (a != (b + 5)) {
                a = b + 5
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MyType2 {
    
    init(a: Int) {
        self.internalA = a
        self.internalB = a - 5
    }
    
    init(b: Int) {
        self.internalB = b
        self.internalA = b + 5
    }

    private var internalA: Int
    private var internalB: Int
    
    var a: Int {
        get { return internalA }
        set(newValue) {
            internalA = newValue
            internalB = newValue - 5
        }
    }
    
    var b: Int {
        get { return internalB }
        set(newValue) {
            internalB = newValue
            internalA = newValue + 5
        }
    }
    
}


I would go with a third option and only store one of the properties and let the other one be computed
struct MyType1 {
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a        
    }

    init(b: Int) {
        self.a = b + 5
        // or self.init(a: b + 5)
    }

    var a: Int
    var b: Int {
        get { a - 5 }
        set { a = newValue + 5 }
    }
}

